# How to pass user's TextFormField input to a button in a different class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a flutter app. For the code reusability, I need to differentiate Email and password forms and Login Button, I am not sure how to properly to pass the input from textformfield to the button for the form to be validated, when clicking it. Here's my code. Note that im a beginner in flutter.

//This is my EmailTextForm class:

```
    class EmailTextForm extends StatelessWidget {
    String email;

   EmailTextForm({Key key, this.email}) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Container(
    width: 370.0,
    height: 54.0,
    child: TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            //DEFAULT STATE OF THE BORDER(FOCUSED BORDER DOWN BELOW TO HAVE MORE CONTROL OF THE FORM)
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                width: 1.0, color: Color.fromRGBO(16, 25, 53, 0.1)),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          //ON FOCUSED BORDER TO NOT CHANGE STATE WHILE BEING PRESSED ON
          borderSide: BorderSide(
              width: 1.0, color: Color.fromRGBO(16, 25, 53, 0.1)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        ),
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail, color: Color(0xFF9FA3AE)),
        hintText: 'El.Paštas',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Sora',
          fontSize: 16.0,
          color: Color(0xFF9FA3AE),
        ),
      ),
      validator: (input) =>
          !input.contains('@') ? 'Please enter a valid email' : null,
      onSaved: (input) => email = input,
    ));
 }
}
```

//This is the button class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class LoginButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String email;
  String password;

  _submit() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      print('validated');
      //logging in the user
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Container to manipulate button design
    return Container(
        width: 370.0,
        height: 54.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular((12.0)),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            //change gradient, wrong value, maybe something in AdobeXD.
            colors: <Color>[Color(0xFF00BAFF), Color(0xFF448CFA)],
            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            begin: Alignment(-1.0, 0.0),
            end: Alignment(1.0, 0.0),
            transform: GradientRotation(math.pi / 2),
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(48, 183, 241, 1.0),
              offset: Offset(0.0, 4.0),
              blurRadius: 12.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),

        //@@@@ WHEN BUTTON IS PRESSED @@@@
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _submit,
          child: Text(
            'Prisijungti',
          ),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              //COLOR OF THE TEXT INSIDE THE BUTTON
              onPrimary: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              ),
              primary: Colors.transparent,
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                //Text inside button style
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontFamily: 'Sora',
              )),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to set the button's text to the value or input text received from the TextFormField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Accessing Field Data

The code sample at bottom shows two different ways to get access to the email field value using:

- `FormFieldState`
- `TextEditingController`

These two methods don't rely on having a `Form` wrapping your fields (although it's often convenient to do so, giving you more options for handling form data & showing validation errors.)

[image]

#### Why use `Form`?

A `Form` widget wrapping fields is useful for handling/manipulating several fields together as a group for things such as form resetting, validation, and submitting.

We access these `Form` functions via a `GlobalKey<FormState>` that we give to the `Form` when we declare it.

```
      child: Form(
        key: formKey, // declared above as a field in our State object
```

For example, `TextFormField` has a `validator:` argument (takes a function).  If our field is inside a `Form`, we can ask the `Form` call all validator functions to "validate" our form:

```
formKey.currentState.validate();
```

The `validator:` will display any non-null String you return to it:

[image: email validator]

#### Code Sample

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FormValuesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Form Values'),
      ),
      body: FormValuesExample(),
    );
  }
}

class FormValuesExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormValuesExampleState createState() => _FormValuesExampleState();
}

class _FormValuesExampleState extends State<FormValuesExample> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  GlobalKey<FormFieldState> emailFieldKey = GlobalKey();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: Form(
        key: formKey, // declared above as a field in our State object
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              key: emailFieldKey,
              controller: emailController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Email'
              ),
              validator: (val) => validateEmail(val),
            ),
            LoginButton(formKey: formKey, fieldKey: emailFieldKey, controller: emailController,)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String validateEmail(String email) {
    if (email == null || email.isEmpty)
      return 'Email cannot be empty';
    return null;
  }
}

class LoginButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey;
  final GlobalKey<FormFieldState> fieldKey;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  LoginButton({this.formKey, this.fieldKey, this.controller});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          formKey.currentState.validate();
          print('from FormFieldState ${fieldKey.currentState.value}');
          print('from controller: ${controller.text}');
        },
        child: Text('Submit'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap them in a Form widget and pass the key, for example:

```
Form(
  key: _keyForm
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
     EmailTextFieldForm(),
     PasswordTextFieldForm(),
     FormButton(),
   ],
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap all the TextFormFields in a form to get it like this

```
Column(
  children: [
    TextFormField(),
    ....
    TextFormField(),
])
```

TextFormFields can be wrapped or moved to another widget, as long as it is a child of the Form.

if everything is in one widget

```
Form(
  child: 
     Column(
     children: [
       TextFormField(),
       ....
       TextFormField(),
       Button(
         onTap: () {},
       ),
])
```

you need to wrap the button in the Builder so that the context of the current element in the tree is available

```
Builder(
  builder: (context) => Button(
    onTap: () {},
  ),
),
```

and after that, you can do `Form.of(context).validate()`. This entry will find the first form higher in the tree and validate all text fields.

in this way you should get out like this

```
Builder(
  builder: (context) => Button(
    onTap: () {
      Form.of(context).validate()
    },
  ),
)
```

if the button is placed in a separate widget, then there is no need to wrap it in the Builder, you can simply call the validation, since the context below the form is available to you

```
Button(
  onTap: () {
    Form.of(context).validate()
  },
),
```

also, you can create GlobalKey

and use validation with a key. You can pass key, for example, through the constructor(if needed)

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

Form(
  key: _formKey
  child: Column(
    children: [
      TextFormField(),
      ....
      Button(
        onTap: () {
          _formKey.currentState!.validate ()
        }
      )
    ],
  ),
 )
```